# Async Wait issues with view updation in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, async-await

In my UWP app, I am updating my UI based on data returned from an API call.
`MyPage` is the page where I show data retuned from API call, this is how I do it:

```
public sealed partial class MyPage : Page
{
    private MyViewModel _viewModel;
    private MyApiResponse _result;
    private string _documentId;

    public DocumentDetailsPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();            
        _viewModel = new MyViewModel();            
    }

    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);    
        _documentId = (string)e.Parameter;
        await GetDocumentDetails();
    }

    private async Task GetDocumentDetails()
    {   
        //THIS WORKS, BUT USING await INSTESD OF .Result DOESN'T UPDATE THE VIEW
        _result =  new MyApiCall(_documentId).GetResponseAsync().Result;
        PrepareViewModel();        
    }

    private void PrepareViewModel()
    {       
        viewModel.Type = _result.response.type;
        viewModel.VolumeNumber = _result.response.volumeNumber;
    }
}
```

This is the class that makes the Http-POST request to the API:

```
public class MyApiCAll
    {
        ...
        ...

        public async Task<MyApiResponse> GetResponseAsync()
        {
            MyApiResponse responseObject;
            using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("ABC", ABC);
                var response =   await _client.PostAsync("someURL", null).ConfigureAwait(false);
                var responseJson =  await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                responseObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyApiResponse>(responseJson);        
            }
            return responseObject;  
        }
    }
```

And here's my view:

```
<StackPanel Style="{StaticResource ContainerStackPanel}"
            Visibility="{x:Bind viewModel.Type, Converter={StaticResource ConverterNameHere}, Mode=OneWay}">
    <TextBlock Text="ABC"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind viewModel.Type, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</StackPanel>

<StackPanel Style="{StaticResource ContainerStackPanel}"
            Visibility="{x:Bind viewModel.volumeNumber, Converter={StaticResource ConverterNameHere}, Mode=OneWay}">
    <TextBlock Text="ABC"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind viewModel.volumeNumber, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

This works perfectly fine except that it blocks the UI so when I remove the `Result` from the method call and add an await like this:

```
_result = await new DocumentDetailsApiCall(_documentId).GetResponseAsync();
```

then, my UI just doesn't show the bound values, it remains blank. I can confirm that the viewModel properties do get updated.

I am not implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` on my ViewModel properties ( I tried implementing it, didn't change anyting )

**UPDATE** As suggested, I have added `INPC` to my viewModel and heres my ViewModel class

```
class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _type;
    public string Type
    {
        get { return _type; }
        set
        {
            _type = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _volumeNumber;
    public string VolumeNumber
    {
        get { return _volumeNumber; }
        set
        {
            _volumeNumber = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }        

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    { 
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The problem remains, I cant use the `await` operator. `.Result` still works.

Comment: It definitely *wont* work unless you have INPC in place; perhaps your implementation was incorrect? Also; whats up with x:Bind over a simple Binding?

Comment: 1) view model should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to update view. That is the whole purpose of having them. 2) remove blocking call `.Result` 3) make sure the property name used in view matches view model property names. ie `volumeNumber` unless that was a typo.

Comment: Without a good [mcve] reliably reproducing the problem, it's impossible to provide an actual answer. But note that the default mode for `{x:Bind}` is `OneTime`. You have correctly set `OneWay` on the bound `Text` properties, but not the `Visibility` properties. So changes to the property values won't affect visibility, once the initial bound value is set.

Comment: Because using .Result instead of await worked perfectly without having INotifyProperryChanged, I thought it would not matter ( also that method is the first and the only place where value is assigned to the viewmodel ). I will make the suggested changes and update my answer.

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside your converter n see if the returned value is Collapsed. Or even, remove the visibility binding n see if anything comes up.

Comment: @JustinXL I removed all the visibility bindings and the result was same.

Comment: Try calling `Bindings.Update()`?

Comment: @JustinXL Perfect. Your previous comment should  be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since calling `Bindings.Update()` fixed your issue, your binding expressions should be correct, but somehow the property change notification fails.

I am not going to guess what really went wrong here but to explain when you should be using `Bindings.Update()`, and when you should be using `INPC` + `OneWay` bindings.

`Bindings.Update()` is only available for `x:Bind`, unlike traditional binding, if your UI rarely needs to update with new data, you don't have to implement `INPC` with your properties, in fact, it's actually much cheaper and more performant doing `OneTime` bindings (with calling `Bindings.Update()`) than implementing `INPC` with `OneWay` bindings.

So, the following will work with `x:Bind` -

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind MyText}" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" />
```

---

```
public string MyText { get; set; }

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyText = "new text!!";
    Bindings.Update();
}
```

Once the Button is clicked, the `TextBlock` will be populated with **new text!!**. Note here I use the default `OneTime` binding (i.e. `{x:Bind MyText}`) and `MyText` is just a a normal CLR property.

This only works because I called `Bindings.Update()` in the end, which forces `OneTime` bindings to be re-initialized.

**However**, like I said earlier, please only consider using the above approach when your UI *rarely* needs to update. Most of the time this is not the case, so you will still implement `INPC` and write `OneWay` binding, without the need of using `Bindings.Update()` at all.